# Is this possible: JPA/Hibernate query with list property in result?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql, jpa-2.0

**In hibernate I want to run this JPQL / HQL query:**

```
select new org.test.userDTO( u.id, u.name, u.securityRoles)
FROM User u
WHERE u.name = :name
```

userDTO class:

```
public class UserDTO {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private List<SecurityRole> securityRoles;

   public UserDTO(Integer id, String name, List<SecurityRole> securityRoles) {
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
     this.securityRoles = securityRoles;
   }

   ...getters and setters...
}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "security_role_id") }
  )
  private List<SecurityRole> securityRoles;

  ...getters and setters...
}
```

But when Hibernate 3.5 (JPA 2) starts I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate 
constructor on class [org.test.UserDTO] [SELECT NEW org.test.UserDTO (u.id,
u.name, u.securityRoles) FROM nl.test.User u WHERE u.name = :name ]
```

**Is a select that includes a list (u.securityRoles) as a result not possible? Should I just create 2 seperate queries?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query without the `NEW` (selecting a scalar value **and** a collection-valued path expression) isn't valid so I don't think that adding a `NEW` will make things work.

For the record, this is what the JPA 2.0 specification says in the section **4.8 SELECT Clause**:

> The SELECT clause has the following
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_item {, select_item}*
> select_item ::= select_expression [ [AS] result_variable]
> select_expression ::=
>          single_valued_path_expression |
>          scalar_expression |
>          aggregate_expression |
>          identification_variable |
>          OBJECT(identification_variable) |
>          constructor_expression
> constructor_expression ::=
>          NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
> constructor_item ::=
>          single_valued_path_expression |
>          scalar_expression |
>          aggregate_expression |
>          identification_variable
> aggregate_expression ::=
>          { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
>          COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
>                   single_valued_object_path_expression)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I should have just looked it up in the JPA spec. Clearly the u.securityRoles is not a 'single_valued_path_expression'. So I guess this means, one has to do separate queries for retrieving collections/relations (or use a join and create the collections with a loop).

Comment: @Kdeveloper If your user has many, many attributes, I guess so. If not, just select the user and fetch his securityRoles.

Comment: @pascal thivent And if the JPQL returns many users, it will eventually result in a loop to retrieve the securityRoles of each User right ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to declare a 0-arg constructor in your `UserDTO` class.

EDIT:
Or a constructor which takes `Integer` instead of `int` as the first argument. When looking up constructors using reflection Hibernate might not treat them as 'compatible' types.

Basically, I would focus on the `Unable to locate appropriate 
constructor on class [...UserDTO]` part of the message.

Comment: I agree, it seems that Hibernate can not find an appropriate constructor. But why? If I remove the securityRoles in both the contructor and query the code works...

Comment: The int to Integer, did not make a difference. The zero argument constructor is not needed, because the HQL explicitly uses the named constructor (or at least it does normally)

Answer (score -2):

I think that you should try something like:

```
select new org.test.userDTO( u.id, u.name, u.securityRoles) AS uDTO,
  uDTO.setRoles(u.securityRoles)
 FROM User u
 WHERE u.name = :name
```

Comment: Your suggestion does not compile.