# DTO Projection of Query with @ElementCollection causes 'Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class' error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, jpql

I'm writing custom query using projection to reduce amount of queries in one session, when couple of field from antity are needed and using Fetch join.
Unfortunately got stuck into a problem when one types in returned dto is a collection.

I have following class with @ElementCollection (siplified version for this purpose):

```
@Entity
class MyClass(

    val someString: String,

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var enums: MutableSet<Enum>,

    @ManyToOne
    var condition: Condition

    //And so on...
)
```

And DTO used for projection:

```
data class ProjectionDTO(
    val aString: String,
    val enumList: List<Enum>
)
```

But when using query:

```
fun query(condition: Condition): List<ProjectionDTO> =
        entityManager.createQuery(
            """SELECT NEW com.xxx.ProjectionDTO( m.someString, e ) FROM MyClass m
                INNER JOIN FETCH m.enums e
                WHERE m.condition = :condition""", ProjectionDTO::class.java)
            .setParameter("condition", condition)
            .resultList
}
```

I get following exception:

```
Exception:[org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.xxx.ProjectionDTO]. Expected arguments are: com.xxx.String, com.xxx.Enum [SELECT NEW com.xxx.ProjectionDTO( m.someString, e ) FROM MyClass m
                INNER JOIN FETCH m.enums e
                WHERE m.condition = :condition]]
```

Already tried different types of collection, additional constructors and calling field of given @ElementCollection like `e.enum` in query params.
Is it possible to return a list (or other collection) from this kind of query? If so, how do I tackle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not allowed to use collection path expressions in constructor query. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678973/2044957)

Put just root entity into constructor:

```
SELECT NEW com.xxx.ProjectionDTO(m) WHERE m.condition = :condition
```

In constructor assign m.enums, m.someString to fields.